# Remove the alert "There are now 0 items in the cart." while using Shopify.clear()

Tags: shopify

How do you remove the alert "There are now 0 items in the cart." while using Shopify.clear(), it's annoying, lol

There are no forums that seems to encounter these issue, or did they just let shopify alert show?

There are no forums that seems to encounter these issue, or did they just let shopify alert show?

Comment: Which theme, and what you tried, and what code issue this, need more details on it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's a custom theme. The only code is Shopify.clear(); when I remove that specific code it doesnt clear the cart but it removes the notification, I only need to remove the notification.

Comment: OK, I saw the old dev's code. the shopify.js was modified. when cart is modified it calls upon a specific function Shopify.onCartUpdate which have the alert();